# Need guidance in creating an EERD

Tags: erd

Hope I'm posting this at the right place. I have an assignment that I've been mulling over in an attempt to understand it completely.

**Instructions**

You are to create an EER diagram from the information provided below using the crow's foot notation.

**The scenario is:**

Rush-Hour Mechanics must keep track of its repair facilities or garages, the mechanics and their qualifications in terms of the courses they have taken, the dates they took the courses and the grade each earned for each course.

Descriptions of these items are as follows (you may add entities and attributes if needed):

Garage: Garage's identification number and manager's name

Mechanic: Employee number and name, a mechanic can be either senior or junior or both

Course: Number, name, duration (in weeks), a course can be either undergraduate or graduate

**My Problem**

I've identified the 3 entities as given (Garage, Mechanic, Course) and given them the attributes mentioned above. My question is how do I represent an entity (e.g Mechanic) as being either a senior, junior or both? Do I just add an attribute called seniority? Its the same for 'Course', how do I represent it being either undergrad or grad?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: You would add reference tables for each of those and provide a relationship between `ExperienceLevel` and `Mechanic` and `CourseLevel` and `Course`.

Comment: Thank you very much.